# Multiple buttons and modals

Tags: javascript, html, events

I'm new to JS and although I have bought some books to start learning properly I wondered if anyone could advise with this? I have store that lists many products. On the store page I have added a button to the bottom of each item and want an action when you click a button. I've applied this code, it works but only on the first element anyway - because it based on id's:

HTML:

```
<button id="myBtn" class="openmodal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
// Get the modal
 window.onload = function(){
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}};
```

I've tried changing the JS to accommodate class names like this, but it didn't work:

```
// Get the modal
 window.onload = function(){
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("openmodal");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}};
```

Please can anyone help?

Thanks in advance
Chris

Comment: add full html code.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` doesn't return a single element, but rather a `NodeList`. You need to extract the required element from this first, e.g. by iterating over it with a `for` loop.

Comment: @Walshie1987, it is working for you ?

Comment: Hi, I'm just out at the minute but I will try this ASAP. It looks very promising! I see where I went wrong. I'll be back to you shortly! Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `classes` instead `ids` because `id` must be unique.

Then you have to **bind** a `click` event handler for each of the buttons, using `onclick` method.

```
<button class="openmodal myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
 <div class="modal myModal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var modals = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("openmodal");
var spans=document.getElementsByClassName("close");
for(let i=0;i<btns.length;i++){
   btns[i].onclick = function() {
      modals[i].style.display = "block";
   }
}
for(let i=0;i<spans.length;i++){
    spans[i].onclick = function() {
       modals[i].style.display = "none";
    }
 }
```

Here is working solution.

```js
var modals = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("openmodal");
var spans=document.getElementsByClassName("close");
for(let i=0;i<btns.length;i++){
    btns[i].onclick = function() {
        modals[i].style.display = "block";
    }
}
for(let i=0;i<spans.length;i++){
    spans[i].onclick = function() {
        modals[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
.modal{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<button class="openmodal myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal myModal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<p>Some text in the Modal1</p>
</div>
</div>
<button class="openmodal myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal myModal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<p>Some text in the Modal2</p>
</div>
</div>
<button class="openmodal myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal myModal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<p>Some text in the Modal3</p>
</div>
</div>
<button class="openmodal myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal myModal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<p>Some text in the Modal4</p>
</div>
</div>
<button class="openmodal myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal myModal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<p>Some text in the Modal5</p>
</div>
</div>
<button class="openmodal myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal myModal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<p>Some text in the Modal6</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Alexandru, I've tested this on Fiddle and it works perfectly, but it doesn't work on my site for some reason. I've added an alert to the code, under where the modal is set: `code` alert( modals[0]); `code` but the output I get is: object HTMLDivElement. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Got it working!! I added in `window.onload = function(){` at the beginning and it was perfect. Also Dreamweaver highlights `let` as a syntax error for some reason, but it still works on my test site. Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

**Varying modal content**
Use `event.relatedTarget` and HTML `data-bs-*` attributes to vary the contents of the modal depending on which button was clicked.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content